# Get different column in each row

Tags: matlab, matrix, row

I would like to get a different column out of each row from a matrix. For example:

```
A = [1,2;1,4;5,2]
B = [2;2;1]
```

the output should yield:

```
out = [2;4;5]
```

So in short: `A` is the matrix and `B` has the indices for the colums per row. How can I do this without using a loop (if it's possible)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html) to convert (i,j) indices to linear indices in matrix A

```
idx = sub2ind(size(A), 1:size(A, 1), B');
A(idx)

ans =

 2     4     5
```

That works assuming that vector B has as many entries as there are rows in A. In the above sub2ind generates a linear index for every pair of subsequent row numbers (1:size(A, 1)) and column numbers given in B.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you. I have to look up the documentation of sub2ind to understand completely how this works.

Answer (score 8):

You can do it by `diag(A(:,B))` , there is however a loop, but only implicit. I don't know how to do it without any loop.

Comment: Just like the answer by using sub2ind, this also does the trick perfectly.

Comment: This method works of course, but on the way it creates an N x N matrix (A(:,B)). This is quite an overhead, when what you really want in the end is a vector of size N.

Comment: Yep, and that's why I chose your answer to be the actual answer :-).