# use vector to select columns of a matlab array

Tags: matlab, matrix, indexing

This is an issue i commonly find myself trying to solve. I have the following:

```
A = [1 2;
     3 4;
     5 6;
     7 8;
     9 10];

B = [1,2,1,2,2];
```

On each row (i) of A, i want to return the value of the column specified in B(i). I currently solve the problem using a loop:

```
result = zeros(size(B));
for i=1:length(B)
    result(i) = A(i,B(i));
end
```

Where result = [1     4     5     8    10]

But this seems inelegant to me. Is there a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could get the correct linear indices using [`sub2ind`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sub2ind.html?refresh=true):

```
rows = (1:numel(B))'
cols = B(:);
ind = sub2ind(size(A), rows, cols);
A(ind)
```

or in a one-liner

```
A(sub2ind(size(A), (1:numel(B))', B(:)))
```

or a more elegant method (taken from the [2nd answer to the duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12672528/matlab-get-different-column-in-each-row))

```
diag(A(:,B))
```

I can't tell you about performance though...

Comment: which of these generalizes to n-D arrays?

Comment: Can you be more specific on what a n-D problem would look like?